# Getting raw bytes from packed struct

Tags: serialization, rust

I've got a struct which looks like this:

```
#[repr(packed)]
struct Header {
    some: u8,
    thing: u8,
}
```

How can I get raw bytes from it, that I could use for either a C library or socket interaction?

I was hoping to use `transmute` to solve the problem, but unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
let header = Header {....}
let header_bytes: &[u8] = unsafe { mem::transmute(header) };
let result = self.socket.write(header_bytes);
```

This fails with

```
error: transmute called on types with different sizes: &Header (64 bits) to &[u8] (128 bits)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit:** updated for Rust 1.x.

You can't transmute arbitrary thing to arbitrary thing (like `Header` to `&[u8]`) because `transmute()` is akin to `reinterpret_cast` in C++: it literally reinterprets the bytes which its argument consists of, and in order for this to be successful the source and the target type should have the same size. But even if `Header` and `&[u8]` had the same size, it wouldn't make sense to convert between them: `Header` is an actual value while `&[u8]` is a pointer with a size of data behind that pointer.

In order to interpret a piece of data as a slice of bytes you need to perform three steps: obtain a raw pointer to the data, convert it to a pointer to `u8` and then convert that to a slice of `u8`. This means enhancing the raw pointer value with the length, which in this case is equal to the structure size. The last step can easily be done with [`std::slice::from_raw_parts()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html):

```
use std::slice;
use std::mem;

let p: *const Header = &header;     // the same operator is used as with references
let p: *const u8 = p as *const u8;  // convert between pointer types
let s: &[u8] = unsafe { 
    slice::from_raw_parts(p, mem::size_of::<Header>())
};
```

However, doing this in most cases is not a good idea. Even though the struct is marked as packed, it still leaves the problem with the byte order, so at the very least the code which does this won't be portable (or rather, the data it serializes in such form may not be recoverable by the same program compiled for another architecture).

Comment: Any chance you know how this is supposed to be done now? Checking the documentation it says that `std::slice::raw::buf_as_slice` is deprecated, but doesn't offer any alternative.

Comment: @HarveyAdcock, I've updated the answer for the latest Rust. In the stable language the preferred way to obtain a slice out of a raw pointer is `std::slice::from_raw_parts()`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. If this wouldn't be a good idea, what other way might you suggest if I'm trying to copy a struct from the stack into a more permanent managed section of memory? I'm making a simple memory allocator, so I would imagine I have to deal with copying the bytes over like this.

Comment: @HarveyAdcock if you're doing this inside your own process for such purposes, I think then this approach is fine. This comment was directed mostly at transferring the data over the network or storing it somewhere externally. In the latter case it is better to use concrete serialization formats, like JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can make any object into a byte slice with a function like this:

```
/// Safe to use with any wholly initialized memory `ptr`
unsafe fn raw_byte_repr<'a, T>(ptr: &'a T) -> &'a [u8]
{
    std::mem::transmute(std::raw::Slice{
        data: ptr as *const _ as *const u8,
        len: std::mem::size_of::<T>(),
    })
}
```

[Run in Rust playpen.](http://is.gd/kLOYon)

I don't know the full safety analysis, but as long as you don't access any uninit values it should be fine.